Problema al generar un bitmap a partir 12 paneles de un formulario
Necesito crear 12 bitmaps uno por cada uno de los 12 paneles (cada panel corresponde a un mes) del formulario de mi aplicación.
El código que utilizo para generar un bitmap por cada uno de esos 12 paneles que uso es el siguiente:
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = pestañas[i];

    if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp"))
         Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp");

            bitmap = new Bitmap(paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height);

            paneles[i].DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height));

            // Ajustar el tamaño del bitmap al tamaño de la página
            bitmap = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, (int)document.PageSize.Width - 40, (int)document.PageSize.Height - 14);
            bitmap.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

            // Crear una instancia de la imagen en el documento PDF
            iTextSharp.text.Image imagen1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            // Agregar una nueva página al documento PDF
            document.NewPage();

            // Añadir la imagen al documento PDF
            document.Add(imagen1);
        }
        // Cerrar el documento PDF
        document.Close();
}

El proceso se realiza correctamente hasta llegar al valor i=11 que corresponde al panel 12 de mi aplicación.
El error (System.ArgumentException: 'El parámetro no es válido.') ocurre en esta línea:
paneles[i].DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height));
Creo que es un tema de recursos, ya que, si hago un dispose al final del bucle de cada uno de los paneles, me genera todos los bitmaps sin error alguno, pero me elimina todos los controles de cada uno de los paneles y yo necesito conservar estos controles.
Un saludo.
Muchas gracias
Disculpen las molestias.

Hola user, bbienvenido, el msj de error debe estar como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo modifiques, a fin de evitar el cierre de loa misma, y/o recibir votos negativos.

12 imágenes no debería dar problemas en ningún computador medianamente moderno, así que el tema de recursos queda descartado.
El ArgumentException en la función DrawToBitmap se produce cuando al menos una de estas situaciones ocurre:

El ancho del rectángulo es igual o menor a cero
El alto del rectángulo es igual o menor a cero
La componente X del rectángulo es menor a cero
La componente Y del rectángulo es menor a cero

Por lo que debes validar que tu panel[11] esté correctamente dimensionado

Buenas, todos esos parametros son correctos, de hecho he creado un botón individual paa ese panel 12 y si lo ejecuto individualmente, no me da ningún error, como comento creo que es tema de recursos ya que si hago un dispose a cada panel después de crear su bitmap correspondiente, no me da ningún error,pero se eliminan todos los controles de los paneles

Como comentaba, si creo un botón para crear la imagen de ese panel en solitario, no me da ningún error y la crea sin problemas, con lo cual entiendo que los parámetros son correctos

Comentar que Tengo los paneles asociados a un tabcontrol donde existen 12 tabpages que son las que contienen los paneles comentados. Para generar el bitmap correspondiente tengo que seleccionar la tabpage correspondiente de esta forma: tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[i];. No se si se puede generar ese bitmap sin tener que ir seleccionando cada vez la tabpage correspondiente, en el caso de que eso si influya de forma importante en los recursos consumidos.
